# Call a standalone script by a SCRIPT in a Google Docs (Document)

Tags: javascript, python, google-apps-script

Call a standalone script by a SCRIPT in a Google Docs (Document)

The aim would be to create a few sort of "Add-on Custom" which is only my documents created with Google Docs Prototype containing a script with a few command line calling a standalone script .

Hi,

Right now, only container-bounded scripts can use "advanced" interactions (create menus, prompts, etc) on a container Spreadsheet, Docs or Forms.

I'd like this ability on a standalone script!

The primary use-case for this is to allow developing and maintain a single script that is used in multiple documents. Because right now, if we have a script that does some nice things on a Spreadsheet (or any other container) we face two major problems.

First, it's very difficult to distribute your script. It often involves multiple steps a end-user have difficulty to do, or have them create the document from a template you setup previously.

And the second problem is maintaining/updating a distributed script, because we have one independent copy on each file. And even if you have access to all files, updating is a nightmare. Even if you use libraries and just need to get in to each one to update the library number (since the library development mode only works if all the users have edit permissions on your library, which is crazy).

If we could have a single standalone script that we, the developers, could control the update/deployment version for all our users/documents, just like we do for web-apps, it would be great!

Lolo

Answer (score 0):

Its called apps script libraries. Check the docs for more detail.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries